# from contour file to shapefile GIS

Tags: gis, contour, data-conversion, elevation

I am trying hard to convert my height contour map into a shapefile containing the height of every single raster cell. I have researched on the internet and all it seems to be done is using the function "topo to Raster", spacial analyst tool. However, using this tool the result is a layer with multi-colored height (this is ok) but it does not even has an attibute table!

Could anybody help me please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe take a look at "Build Raster Attribute Table" in the ArcGIS Raster toolset? (This question might be better asked on [GIS StackExchange](http://http://gis.stackexchange.com).)

Answer (score 0):

Without test with data it's difficult to be sure but have a look at saga GIS, free and open source
 http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html .
It works well with raster and shp together. 
Even openjump with sextante inside can help you .
Luca